# Users after registration cant login

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hello im running wordpress 5.2.2 version and i have an issue the login part!
When new users register a account and logout they cant re login again!
Using Magic registration plugin!!
ERROR: The password you entered for the username % is incorrect. Lost your password?

Comment: How is the account created?  Does the pass hash get created correctly? - See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/

Comment: yeah the hash is correct

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using a plugin if at all possible.

You can customise the registration/login pages very easily by looking at the WordPress documentation here: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

By doing it this way, you maintain control and avoid the need to run any heavy code on your site.

If you do need to use a plugin, I'd recommend this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/